# Select * from table always misses first row result

Tags: mysql, database

I expect this is a simple coding error.
When trying to get all results from database table, the first result is always missed off. Even when adding and removing information to the database it will always miss off the result with the lowest ID.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_messages") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ); 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<a href=\"../message/index.php?user=\">" .$info['subject']. "</a>";
  echo "<hr>";
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the first `mysql_fetch_array` statement.

something like

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_messages") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<a href=\"../message/index.php?user=\">" .$info['subject']. "</a>";
  echo "<hr>";
 }
```

You are skipping the first entry by using the code as above.

From [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the
>   internal data pointer ahead.

Which means that when you get to the while, you have already read the first row, but not used it yet.

Comment: AHH, YOU GENIUS! That worked, I knew it would be something simple. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code calls `mysql_fetch_array` and assigns the result (the first row of the result set) to `$info`.  You don't do anything with `$info`, and in the next line you overwrite it with another call to `mysql_fetch_array`.

You need to delete this line:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

Answer (score 1):

From the php manual:

> ```
> array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
> ```
>
> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

So after
`$data = mysql_query(...)` you get an array `$data` and the internal data pointer points on the first element of `$data`.

The first call of `mysql_fetch_array(...)` moves the internal data point ahead, so it now points to the second element.

Then, your while-loop calls `mysql_fetch_array(...)` AGAIN before issuing the first Print, so the second element gets printed.

You can fix it by removing this line:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had problems like this too with my table query's ignoring row 0 (the first occurance) and now that I see this I finally understand what's going on.

The clarification is also understandable.

You are asking for a query_fetch_array and you put what it finds in `$info`. This seems ok. Next you ask for the remaining rows, since you just removed one row from the possible returns, it also works perfectly.

Remove this line:

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

and you get all your rows from your table. Or, if you are wondering, ECHO the `$info` before your `while` loop in the fashion you are printing or just try `var_dump`ing it.